# Angular Material: Test Harness - how to check if input has class 'ng-dirty'?

Tags: angular, angular-material, automated-tests

With the [component test harness](https://material.angular.io/guide/using-component-harnesses), we should develop our test based on PageObject structure that gives us everything we should know about that element.

I have a test that I need to check if the input is dirty. How is the right way to do that with Component Harness? I know I can access the element and get the class, but it does not look the right way. Is there any ReactiveFormHarness ?

Component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'sdx-input-harness',
  template: `
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [formControl]="formControl" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  </mat-form-field>`
})
export class InputHarnessComponent {
  public formControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
}
```

Component test:

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { HarnessLoader } from '@angular/cdk/testing';
import {TestbedHarnessEnvironment} from '@angular/cdk/testing/testbed';
import { MatInputHarness } from '@angular/material/input/testing';

import { InputHarnessComponent } from './input-harness.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

describe('InputHarnessComponent', () => {
  let component: InputHarnessComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InputHarnessComponent>;
  let loader: HarnessLoader;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ InputHarnessComponent ],
      imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, MatInputModule, MatFormFieldModule, NoopAnimationsModule ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InputHarnessComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create', async () => {
    const input = await loader.getHarness<MatInputHarness>(MatInputHarness.with({ selector: '#name' }));
    
    await input.focus();
    await input.setValue('New value');

    await fixture.detectChanges();
    const com = fixture.nativeElement;

    // works! but it does not sound like the right way ---------------------------------
    const host = await input.host();
    const className = await host.getAttribute('class');
    expect(className.includes('ng-dirty')).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the first time I am seeing `TestbedHarnessEnvironment` but I would change the last 3 lines to:

```
const inputAfterChange = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#name.ng-dirty'));
expect(inputAfterChange).toBeTruthy();
```

We query the dom for the element with CSS selector '#name.ng-dirty' and we ensure it exists.